# Understanding recursion concept using two recursions

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, stack

I am trying to solve merge sort and i am getting lost in recursion concept. So to make myself understand better, i framed a small example.

With `n= 2` for below program i get answer as as `0,1,2` which i totally understand concept of using stack and returning values of stack one by one through `puts n` after finishing recursion.

```
 def one(n)
  if n < 0
   return
  end
  one(n-1)
  puts n
 end
```

But when i am trying to using another recursion like below i am totally lost on why and how is the answer `0,0,1,0,0,1,2` . Can anyone simply explain it ?

```
 def one(n)
  if n < 0
   return
  end
  one(n-1)
  one(n-1)
  puts n
 end
```

Please add enough description on how does both recursions works together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pictorial representation of your second recursion.  The rows indicate the order of the operations; the columns the recursion level:

```
n = 2
return if n < 0
one(1) ->        n=1
                 return if n < 0
                 one(0) ->        n=0
                                  return if n < 0
                                  one(-1) ->       n=-1
                                                   return if n < 0
                                                   <-

                                  one(-1) ->       n=-1
                                                   return if n < 0
                                                   <-
                                  puts 0
                                  <-

                 one(0) ->        n=0
                                  return if n < 0
                                  one(-1) ->       n=-1
                                                   return if n < 0
                                                   <-

                                  one(-1) ->       n=-1
                                                   return if n < 0
                                                   <-
                                  puts 0
                                  <-
                 puts 1
                 <-

  one(1) ->      n=1
                 << same as above, resulting in `puts 0`, `puts 0`, `puts 1` >>
                 <-
  puts 2
```

Think of each recursion level (column) as though it were a separate method. It performs some operations then calls another method.  In this case it calls itself, but you shouldn't think of it that way; just think of it as calling some method. Eventually that method returns, possibly with a value (but not here), and the method continues on to the next statement (row) in the normal way. Eventually it returns to the method that called it.  That happens to be the same method, but again, think of it as just some method.

By constrast, this is what is happening with your first recursion:

```
n = 2
return if n < 0
one(1) ->        n=1
                 return if n < 0
                 one(0) ->        n=0
                                  return if n < 0
                                  one(-1) ->       n=-1
                                                   return if n < 0
                                                   <-
                                  puts 0
                                  <-
                 puts 1
                 <-
puts 2
```

Comment: can you explain a bit in words ? ..i mean in first example ..why does my recursion complete and then print ? and in second example ..why does for each first recursion, second recursion is occuring ?

Answer (score 1):

`one(n)` calls `one(n-1)` twice, then calls `puts n`, so it looks like:

```
one(2) -> one(1) -> one(0) -> one(-1) 
                           \> one(-1) 
                           \> puts 0  
                 \> one(0) -> one(-1) 
                           \> one(-1) 
                           \> puts 0
                 \> puts 1
       \> one(1) -> one(0) -> one(-1) 
                           \> one(-1) 
                           \> puts 0
                 \> one(0) -> one(-1) 
                           \> one(-1) 
                           \> puts 0
                 \> puts 1
       \> puts 2
```

The functions in the above image are called like this: `one(2)` calls `one(1)`, which calls `one(0)`, which then calls `one(-1)`, this `one(-1)` returns, one(0) calls the second `one(-1)`, the second `one(-1)` returns, `one(0)` calls `puts 0`, then `one(0)` returns, back to the second `one(0)`, etc.

Comment: can you explain a bit in words ? ..i mean in first example ..why does my recursion complete and then print ? and in second example ..why does for each first recursion, second recursion is occuring ?

Comment: @RahulSambari Added a little explanation. Take a pencil and see if you can figure it out on paper.